# converting varchar to int when copying tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, data-structures

I wrote a code which inserts values from a varchar table into a structured table in my DB
I used this schema:

**

```
insert int Table1 (field1, field 2 .....)
select cast (field1 to date) as field1, cast (field2 as int) as field2 .......
from table1_Temp**
```

now I get this error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

How can I know which field is the problematic and how can I sort this out?

Thanks,

Boris

Comment: What values are you inserting? Maybe there is something contains non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know that you are converting field2 to a numeric type, you can try this:

```
SELECT field2
  FROM table1_Temp
 WHERE IsNumeric(field2) = 0
```

and in case iterate for the other columns or with OR you can test multiple fields at the same time.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1_Temp
 WHERE IsNumeric(field2) = 0
    OR IsNumeric(field3) = 0    
   ...
    OR IsNumeric(fieldN) = 0
```

Comment: But the varchar data is coming from table1_Temp.
Table1 is still empty because I get the error.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I didn't double check the name of the source table. The field(s) that you have to test is in the source table. I have edited my answer.